# Projects dependencies for custom configuration

Tags: ios, cocoapods

We are using cocoapods to link different projects together. We have a main project with a target (`project1`) that has 3 configurations `release`, `debug` and a custom duplicate of release, `qa`.

We have 3 external libraries that `project1` depends on that are not cocoapod compatible, let's call those `external1`, `external2` and `external3`. Those external projects only have 2 configurations, the default `release` and `debug`.

Our Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
workspace 'project1.xcworkspace'

pod ...
pod ...

target 'project1'
target 'project1-cal'

target 'external1' do
  project '[...]/external1.xcodeproj', 'qa' => :release
end

target 'external2' do
  project '[...]/external2.xcodeproj', 'qa' => :release
end

target 'external3' do
  project '[...]/external3.xcodeproj', 'qa' => :release
end
```

this setup fails when I try to build for Qa with the following error:

`Showing All Messages
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-external1`

The only way I can fix this is by manually adding `qa` configurations to `external1`, `external2` and `external3`.

Can someone please help with this, by explaining what I am doing wrong? I lack some depth knowledge of how exactly cocoapod work.

N.B: `Pods-external*.qa.xcconfig` are being properly created by `pod install` in `Target Support Files/Pods-external1` albeit they aren't appearing in xcode and also no `qa` configuration are being added.